# How to do decompose conditional refactoring?

Tags: php, if-statement, refactoring, conditional-statements

I've this situation in code where i think the code is unnecessary complex and i believe i can refactor it to make it more easier to understand and read.
So i googled about it and found decompose conditional refactoring, but i'm still in doubt how to do refactoring

```
if(count($bagTypes) == 1 && (array_key_exists('type1', $bagTypes)
    || array_key_exists('type2', $bagTypes)
    || array_key_exists('type3', $bagTypes))){
        $flag = 1;
}

if(count($bagTypes) == 2 && (
    (array_key_exists('type1', $bagTypes) && array_key_exists('type2', $bagTypes)) ||
    (array_key_exists('type1', $bagTypes) && array_key_exists('type3', $bagTypes)) ||
    (array_key_exists('type2', $bagTypes) && array_key_exists('type3', $bagTypes)))
){
    $flag = 1;
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$arrayKeys = array(
    'type1',
    'type2',
    'type3'
);

$bagTypesKeys = array_keys($bagTypes);

if ((count($bagTypes) == 1 && count(array_diff($arrayKeys, $bagTypesKeys)) < 3)
    || (count($bagTypes) == 2 && count(array_diff($arrayKeys, $bagTypesKeys)) < 2))
{
    $flag = 1;
}
```